# FlowJS - does not recognize when there is a value on an optional field

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I have the following type definition (note that `path` is optional):

```
type MyType = {
  name: string,
  path?: Array<string>
};
```

Then in my code I have certain places where `path` **definitely** has a value:

```
const meta: MyType = {
  name: 'Foo',
  path: []
}

meta.path.unshift('bar');
```

In the above example `meta.path` has a value, but flow complains that it cannot call "unshift" on undefined. I get that `undefined` is a valid value for `path`, but in this case `path` **definitely** has a value 100% percent of the time. The only way to fix it is to this completely unnecessary code:

```
(meta.path || []).unshift(...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Flow knows is that `const meta` is of type `MyType`, and that `MyType` has `path` which is optional. It doesn't know whether `path` exists or not, and so it correctly throws that error.

If you want `path`, you need to wrap it in some sort of if check or something similar to what you have done.

Comment: But that still doesn't make sense though. If I add `if(!meta.path) meta.path = [];`, flow recognizes that `path` has a value and the error goes away. Why can it not see that `path` has value in the initial variable declaration? It seems that flow discerns between _how_ a value is assigned, which is confusing and results in disgusting code bloat. I'm trying to jump on the types train, but my code is nearly unreadable in places.